# Buttons get stuck on highlighted

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, uiscrollview, touchesbegan

I have just started working on a project and I already have a few problems and errors. I was wondering if you guys could help me figure out where the bug is.

**Quick overview:** I have two files: (ViewController.m and Scroller.m). In the ViewController I have some code under ViewDidLoad (which I'll show in a second), I also have a function (addImagesToView) that does what it says, and some touchesBegan,moved and ended for intractability.

In the Scroller I decided to rewrite some of the "-(void)touches" functions implementations.

**The problem I have:**  is that the buttons (coming from the addImagesToView function) get stuck on highlighted. I performed some tests with an NSLog to see which "touches" working and which don't. "touchesMoved" doesn't work properly. If the user drags downward, the log stops after about 3 or 4 lines of text. I think that it interferes with the scroll somehow.

This is the content of ViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgPNG.png"]];

    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

    //UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:imageView.image];
    //self.view.backgroundColor = background;

    CGRect fullScreen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

    scroll = [[Scroller alloc] initWithFrame:fullScreen];
    scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 2730);

    scroll.delaysContentTouches = NO;
    //scroll.canCancelContentTouches = NO;
    scroll.scrollEnabled  = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:scroll];

    buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [self addImagesToView];



}

-(void) addImagesToView{




    CGFloat yCoordinate = 35;

    for (int i=1; i<=18; i++) {

        UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"picture%d.png",i]]highlightedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"picture%dHG.png",i]]];

        CGRect position = CGRectMake(105, yCoordinate, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE);
        image.frame = position;

        [scroll addSubview:image];

        image.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        image.tag = i;

        [buttons addObject:image];
        yCoordinate += 150;


    }
}

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // Get any touch
    UITouch *t = [touches anyObject];


    if ([t.view class] == [UIImageView class])
    {

        // Get the tappedImageView
        UIImageView *tappedImageView = (UIImageView*) t.view;
        tappedImageView.highlighted = YES;
    }
}

-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *t = [touches anyObject];
    if ([t.view class] == [UIImageView class])
    {

        // Get the tappedImageView
        UIImageView *tappedImageView = (UIImageView*) t.view;
        tappedImageView.highlighted = NO;
    }

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources th at can be recreated.
}

@end
```

and this is the Scroller.m

```
#import "Scroller.h"

@implementation Scroller

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (!self.dragging)
        [self.nextResponder touchesBegan: touches withEvent:event];
    else
        [super touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];
}

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *t = [touches anyObject];
    if ([t.view class] == [UIImageView class])
    {

        // Get the tappedImageView
        UIImageView *tappedImageView = (UIImageView*) t.view;
        tappedImageView.highlighted = NO;
    }

}


-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (!self.dragging)
        [self.nextResponder touchesEnded: touches withEvent:event];
    else
        [super touchesEnded: touches withEvent: event];        // Get the tappedImageView

}

/*
 // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
 // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
 {
 // Drawing code
 }
 */

@end
```

I have also tried to implement all the touches in the ViewController, but I don't know how to make it read from the scroll (please notice the diff. between SCROLL and SCROLLER).

As you can tell I've tried to order them like this: view -> backGroundImage ->scroller ->addImagesToView(function), so that the images that come out from [I]addImagesToView[/I] are on top of the scroll. That's my desired hierarchy.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to write your own touch handling routines for button presses.  Instead of using `UIImageView`s, just create `UIButton`s instead and hook into their `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` event.

Comment: So, do you think it would work better with UIButton obj. instead of UIImageViews? The buttons I'm trying to make are customized PNGs.

Comment: Yes, use a button, this is exactly what they are designed for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off telling us what you are trying to accomplish as you're probably barking up the wrong tree here.  As Jim said, there are better ways to select images, and even if you want to handle touches yourself, UIGestureRecognizers are probably a better option.  If you are allowing users to select images, I'd recommend you take a look at iCarousel on github.  It's an open source carousel that works great for image selection.  Also, if you can target iOS 6 there is a new collection view that could be right up your alley.

Comment: My basic idea is to have a view with a bg, a scroll and some images on that scroll coming out of addImagesToView function. The images are buttons that I made in photoshop in two versions: normal & highlighted. Could you tell me a bit more about the collection view for the iOS 6? Thanks.